# map two strings in two different files which share the same number in the beginning of line in bash

Tags: bash

I have two files. One contains animal names:

```
martin@potato:~$ cat animals.txt 
98 white elefant
103 brown dog
111 yellow cat
138 blue whale
987 pink pig
martin@potato:~$
```

..and other contains places where they live:

```
martin@potato:~$ cat places.txt 
98 safari
99
103 home
105
109
111 flat
138 ocean
500
987 farm
989
martin@potato:~$
```

Number before animal name in animals.txt points to correct place. Output should be like this:

```
martin@potato:~$ ./animals.sh
safari  white elefant
home    brown dog
flat    yellow cat
ocean   blue whale
farm    pink pig
martin@potato:~$
```

What is the most elegant solution in bash to map animal name with location?

I did it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#content of animals.txt file is stored into "$animals" variable using command substitution
animals=$(<animals.txt)

#content of places.txt file is stored into "$places" variable using command substitution
places=$(<places.txt)


#read(bash builtin) reads "$animals" variable line by line
while read line; do

    #"$animals_number" variable contains number in the beginning of the line; for example "98" in case of first line
    animals_number=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/ .*$//')
    #"$animals_name" variable contains string after number; for example "white elefant" in case of first line
    animals_name=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[0-9]* //')
    #"$animals_place" variable contains the string after line which starts with "$animals_number" integer in places.txt file;
    #for example "safari" in case of first line
    animals_place=$(echo "$places" | grep -Ew "^$animals_number" | sed 's/.* //')
    #printf is used to map two strings which share the same integer in the beginning of the line
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$animals_place" "$animals_name"

#process substitution is used to redirect content of "$animals" variable into sdtin of while loop
done < <(echo "$animals")
```

However, I'm not sure this is the most elegant/efficient way to solve this problem. Any additional methods/techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read id place;  do places[$id]=$place;                           done < places.txt
while read id animal; do printf '%s\t%s\n' "${places[$id]}" "$animal"; done < animals.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
join <(sort animals.txt) <(sort places.txt) | sort -n
```

Unfortunately, `join` does not have a "numerically sorted" option, afaik; otherwise you could just `join` the two files instead of sorting everything twice. (If you put leading zeros into the files, it would work without the `sort`s, too.)

Recent ubuntus, and probably other Linux distros, set `LANG` to your presumed locale. This is fatal for `sort`, which is locale-aware, unlike `join`; for the above to work, `join` and `sort` must agree about sortation order. If you get an error like:

```
join: /dev/fd/63:5: is not sorted: 98 white elefant
```

then try this:

```
( export LC_ALL=C;  join <(sort animals.txt) <(sort places.txt) | sort -n )
```